# Reuse elements in TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

How to make components reusable in TornadoFX? Lets assume I have tableview defined like this:

```
tableview<MyObj>(items) {
    column("name", MyObj::name)
    column("value", MyObj::value)
}
```

Can I somehow wrap it to reuse the same columns in another views? To use it like

```
mytableview(items)
```

This way I won't duplicate any columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a factory function!

```
fun EventTarget.myobjtable(items: ObservableList<MyObj>, op: TableView<MyObj>.() -> Unit = {}) =
    tableview(items) {
        column("name", MyObj::name)
        column("value", MyObj::value)
        op()
    }
```

This should work the same as calling the original `tableview` function, just with the columns already added in.